# Python: how can I get rid of the second element of each sublist?

Tags: python

I have a list of sublists, such as:

[[501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4]]

How can I get rid of the second element for each sublist ? (i.e. 4)

[501, 501, 501, 501]

Should I iterate the list or is there a faster way ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [[501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4]]
b = [c[0] for c in a]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension to take the first element of each sublist:

```
xs = [[501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4]]
[x[0] for x in xs]
# [501, 501, 501, 501]
```

Answer (score 2):

A less pythonic, functional version using `map`:

```
a = [[501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4], [501, 4]]
map(lambda x: x[0], a)
```

Less pythonic, since it does not use list comprehensions. See [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: I deleted my comment because wikipedia disagreed with me about what the first language with list comprehensions was, but you misunderstood me: My point was that using list comprehensions is just as functional as using `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @sepp2k I deleted mine too. And I agree with you. I intended this to be a nice complementary answer for people.